# trying to read objects from a file and after getting some records CORRECTLY my program detects eof,many records are left

Tags: c++, file-handling, ifstream, eof

I am trying to read records from a file into objects. but after reading some records CORRECTLY, program detects end of file, even though there are many more records in the file. I have written the records on the file using objects of same class and I can't understand whats going wrong.

here is my code-

```
    int main()
         {
            long int n=0;
            class_name objt[100];
            ifstream fl;
            fl.open(filename);
            cout<<"Scanning file"<<endl<<"Please Wait"<<endl;
            while(true)
              {
                  fl.read((char*)&objt[n], sizeof(objt[n]));
    
                  if(fl.eof())
                   {
                      cout<<endl<<"END OF FILE"<<endl<<"Press any key to continue";
                      cin.get();
                      break;
                   }
                  n++;
             }
             fl.close();
             cout<<endl<<"Scanning Complete!"
```

this is the class i am using-

```
class class_name
         {
           public:
           char name[20];
           double cn ;
           int code;
           int unit;
        };
```

P.S. I want to save all the records into an array of object so as to sort the array

Comment: If you  think the code that writes the file you're now-reading isn't relevant, think again.

Comment: Tip: Use `std::vector<class_name>` and `push_back` one record at a time. Don't *assume* 100 will do it, because it probably won't.

Comment: Tip: Instead of reading raw binary structures in, use `operator<<` and `operator>>` to define serialization and deserialization methods so this can operate on a stream directly. There's no need for low-level `read` calls.

Comment: You shouldn't be opening in text mode for binary data - it can do very strange things, in particular on Windows.

Comment: The file I am trying to read is a .txt file and I have filled records in this file by generating random numbers using rand().

Comment: I have written these records using file_obj.write so to access them I have to use file-obj.read...

Comment: Moreover I am not using a vector (atleast for now) is because I know how many records are present

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do binary I/O then you must open your file in binary mode (for both reading and writing)

```
        ifstream fl;
        fl.open(filename, ios_base::binary);
```